# Scheme duplicate entries in a list

Tags: list, scheme, double, racket

I'm trying to duplicate all the entries in a list using Scheme:

This is the code I have:

```
(define double
  (lambda (l)
    (cond [(null? l) '()]
          [(not (pair? l)) (list l l)]
          [else (cons (double (car l)) (double (cdr l)))])))
```

If my input is `(double '(a((b)(c d)(((e))))))`, I get back `((a a) (((b b)) ((c c) (d d)) ((((e e))))))`.

I want to get `(a a((b b)(c c d d)(((e e)))))`.

How would I do this? If I replace `cons` with `append` or `list`, it messes up even more. I can only use the commands you see up there and commands such as `let` (and other variations of let), `map`, `atom`, `if` and other logical operators.

Comment: Note: You want to duplicate the elements in a tree (not a list).

Comment: The word list implies one level. The word tree implies you want to duplicate the elements on all levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second condition has to be handled a bit differently for this to work, in essence, we have to stop not when we reach an atom, but when we reach a list whose first element is an atom - in this way we can rebuild the output list as needed. Try this:

```
(define double
  (lambda (l)
    (cond [(null? l) '()]
          [(not (pair? (car l)))
           (cons (car l)
                 (cons (car l)
                       (double (cdr l))))]
          [else (cons (double (car l))
                      (double (cdr l)))])))
```

Now it works as expected:

```
(double '(a ((b) (c d) (((e))))))
=> '(a a ((b b) (c c d d) (((e e)))))
```